# Rel canonical without a primary URL

Tags: html, seo, canonical-link

**Background**: We have a situation where the customer can select in which places to publish a content on a website. If it’s a municipality website, an article describing a playground could be published both in the “For families” section and “Parks” section. In some government site with instructions for companies divided into sections by company types: Instructions that are identical for all companies will be published in all company type sections.  There is often no definite primary place that is more right than the others.

The CMS renders top, bottom and side content relevant to the part of the site where you are, so only the content part is identical between locations.

**Questions**:

1. Do I need rel canonical for URLs inside the same site, or is it only for external links?
2. If I need them, can I somehow specify that they are all “primary” or did I already do that by not having a the canonical tag at all?
3. Do search engines generally show pages that has the canonical tag?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the behaviour of a search engine service / asking for SEO advice. (It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].)

Comment: On the other hand, it asks about code. Thus it qualifies as programming-related and is off-topic on [Webmasters.SE]. I believe it is on-topic here and should be answered. The third part is a crystal ball question anywhere, nobody can know for sure what Google will or won’t do; I guess no answer is needed for that part.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to merge internal pages, then yes, a canonical is required for those pages.
2. By setting a canonical, the target URL will be displayed preferably by Google.
3. No, they display the page that is linked to in the canonical.